# ckeditor5 not saving images in civicrm / Drupal9

Tags: ckeditor5, drupal-9, civicrm

I've installed Drupal-9 using Composer and civicrm (5.64) as well and am using php8.1 on a Ubuntu 22 Linode server.
When I edit a Mailing Template by uploading an image and click save, I get a success alert but the image is not actually saved. It doesn't appear in the editor nor is the image uploaded to the images upload directory which is set to [civicrm.files]/persist/contribute/images/.

The image folder is owned by www-data:www-data with 775. I tried copying a .png file to the folder and pointing a browser to https://subdomain.siteimworkingon.org/sites/default/files/civicrm/persist/contribute/images/gbc.png
it displays the image. If I use developer tools and watch Network tab while I am saving the template there is no obvious post errors or anything I can see.
I've also tried summernote editor with similar issues.
I believe it must be a path or permission issue but I've reached the end of my troubleshooting skills. Any help will be much appreciated!

Al

Comment: You may get more civi-wise eyeballs at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've posted at https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45426/ckeditor5-not-saving-images-in-civicrm-drupal9